# e.which only working with capital letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been messing with JQuery codes that will only run on key presses, and they are not working unless I type a capital letter. Has anyone else had this issue?

Ex:

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 70) {
    console.log("test");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Only works if i type "F," but not "f"

Comment: Of course, when using `keypress` the `F` is 70 but `f` is 102

Comment: You shouldn't use `e.which` (or  `e.keyCode`) at all, it's long deprecated and returns ambigous results depending on OS/browser/language. Use `e.key` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to the `keydown` event instead of the `keypress` event, and it works as expected:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 70) {
    console.log("test");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works [because](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events.

So, to check that the "f" key has been depressed, use `keydown` to check the *key* that was depressed (the `.which` property will hold the `keyCode` of the capital letter of the pressed key, no matter whether shift is down or not), while "keypress" will have the `keyCode` of the *character* that would get typed, which would be "F" if shift is down (keycode of 70, which is not the same as the keycode for "f", which is 102)

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't expect that, I would've expected it to use the lowercase code without modifiers

Comment: @LGSon: From what I know, `102` is the number 6 on the keyboard numpad... So I don't get your comment.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette [.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is confusing,  it `returns the numeric keyCode of the key pressed, or the character code (charCode) for an alphanumeric key pressed`. So alphanumerics do *not* return their associated `keyCode`, and `String.fromCharCode(102) === 'f'`

Comment: I don't want to ague to much on that... But I have to remind that OP's question is about jQuery [e.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)... ;) and not about the deprecated JS [e.wich)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which]... Yes... That is confusing enought.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yep, I thought that jQuery might have been doing something odd, but in this case, vanilla JS has the same issue when listening to `keypress` events and checking their `which` property

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `which` is different in jQuery... But not confident enought to prove it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I attempted an answer anyway... Since that aspect of the question is bugging me.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Do note, OP used `keypress`, and with that the `e.which` value is different than with `keydown`, hence my comment, and also the main reason OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette And no, `which` is not different in jQuery. Simply change your answer's event to `keypress` and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The `keyDown` usage suggested by [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) is absolutely correct. But I just wish to add-on a detail about `e.which` in jQuery.

The `e.which` event property is ***different*** in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) than in [vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)... Where it is "normalized".
It actually is deprecated for vanilla JS, but absolutely not for jQuery.

From jQuery's documentation:

> Most properties from the original event are copied over **and normalized** to the new event object.

Now if you want to make the difference between <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd>, you have to use the `e.shiftKey` property in your logic.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 70 && !e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Lowercase f");
  }
  if (e.which == 70 && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Uppercase F");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*And yes... That is really confusing.*

Comment: That is correct, and for the `keydown` event your solution will work, but not when using the `keypress` event, which is what OP used in their question.